# Tricks for classification problems where one class is predominant?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, detection

Imagine you have two classes A and B, and you need to distinguish between them. Normally I'd just train a normal classifier on the data (e.g. logistic regression, backprop net) and be done with it. But I notice that A occurs several orders of magnitude more frequently than than B does! Should present the classifier with the data distribution as is, or change it such that the classes are equally frequent? Or would more drastic changes be helpful? I imagine this case has been studied a lot previously (e.g. face detection), but I'm somewhat unfamiliar with how much the techniques differ from regular old classification.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942617/anomaly-classification-probability-on-machine-learning/28008178#28008178

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to deal with so called "imbalanced datasets", e.g. oversampling, and custom costs matrices and class priors.

I generally prefer to keep the problem as it is, but be sure to study the performance classwise. If a classifier for instance does 20% errors on a dataset with two classes, one of which only accounts for 25% of the observations, you need the classwise errors to tell if it is doing a good overall job or just neglecting the minor class.

A good introduction can be found in [Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery Handbook](https://books.google.se/books?id=S-XvEQWABeUC), chapter 40, [Data mining for imbalanced datasets: An overview](https://www3.nd.edu/~dial/papers/SPRINGER05.pdf). (NB, I think the pdf obtained with the latter link is publicly available, but it is hard to tell from within the university network I'm working from.)